# How do you align or hide background images in a javascript slideshow?

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I've created a slideshow on a website (sorry, new user and can only post one link) using this method: http://iamacamera.org/sandbox/linkedphotoshuffler/ I only changed the specified variables, and it works great, except that about 10 or so pixels of the right edge of the image currently in the background are showing. I've checked, and the images are exactly the same size, so there appears to be a shift left of the foreground image or shift right of the image in the background. How do I ensure they are perfectly aligned or hide the background image so it is not visible to users?

Comment: Post your link........................

Answer (score 0):

Disable any CSS not necessary to make this work and see if maybe one of the CSS rules for your site is accidentally targeting the div holding the image and applying a margin or padding.

Comment: Found a padding element that I tweaked to accomplish this. I've got a few pixels below it that I haven't solved, but thanks for the suggestion! Definitely got me headed in the right direction.

Comment: If you don't have it installed, install Firebug for Firefox. It will let you view the applied styles of a particular page element. I've used it time and time again to find out which styles are active. You can even modify them on the fly to see what changes would look like.